# Regex in SSMS for @

Tags: sql-server, regex

In standard regex if I have this expression `[@][1-9A-Za-z]+` then is finds two matches in here:

```
Hello @world you are better then @2world honestly.
```

It seems like in SSMS the `@` is a regex operator - how do I change my expression to get the escape value for `@`?

---

**note**
This functionality is supported in Find & Replace

[image]

Comment: You already put the at symbol in brackets.  Is this not working for you?  Can you show your query?

Comment: AFAIK Sql server does not support regEx outside of a clr function.

Comment: this would not work in a query ... it is in Find & Replace where a fuller version of regex is implemented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to escape it- \@[1-9A-Za-z]+

Comment: Thanks - although I've already decided it makes more sense to save the `.sql` file - open it in Notepad++ and use standard regex. This is another MS phenomenon where I ask "Why?"